# What is wrong with this code for web crawler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-crawler

So, What I'm basically trying to do is, to find links a particular page has(10 here). Everything works fine, I even get the indices correctly(startlink, startquote, endquote). But, URL is not printing. Why is it? And, What went wrong? If you can correct it, I'll be glad!

```
def web():
n=0
a=open('quora.txt', 'r') #I've saved it as a txt file in my system
b=a.read()
startlink=0
while(n<10):
    startlink=b.find('<a href=', startlink+1)
    startquote=b.find('"', startlink)
    endquote=b.find('"', startquote)
    url=b[startquote+1:endquote]
    print url, startlink, startquote, endquote
    n=n+1
```

And this is the output I get, Only the indices. No, URL

```
4506 4514 4514
5308 5316 5316
5357 5365 5365
5472 5480 5480
5515 5523 5523
5588 5596 5596
5639 5647 5647
5723 5731 5731
6828 6836 6836
6867 6875 6875
```

Answer (score 0):

The search for endquote should start one character after the position of startquote:

```
def web():
    n = 0
    a = open('quora.txt', 'r') #I've saved it as a txt file in my system
    b = a.read()
    startlink = 0
    while (n < 10):
        startlink = b.find('<a href=', startlink + 1)
        startquote = b.find('"', startlink)
        endquote = b.find('"', startquote + 1)
        url = b[startquote + 1:endquote]
        print url, startlink, startquote, endquote
        n = n + 1
```

because now it matches the same startquote for endquote as well

Comment: I've tried to improve the code a bit. And. wrote this. But, I find not all the links are being checked/printed. 
def get_next_target(page):
 startlink=page.find('<a href=')
 startquote=page.find("'", startlink)
 endquote=page.find("'", startquote+1)
 url=page[startquote+1:endquote]
 page[endquote:]
 return url, endquote

 
def get_all_links(page):
 links=[]
 while True:
  url, endpos=get_next_target(page)
  if url:
   links.append(url)
   page=page[endpos:]
  else:
   break
 print links
 
 
if __name__=='__main__':
 get_all_links(page)

Comment: well the approach you took to find links on the page could very easily break, html is hard to parse. what if `<a href` has two spaces instead of one? with broken html or strangely formatted html, it surely might not find all links on a page. you should check out an html parser library, like lxml for instance..